# OnTouchEvent issue

Tags: android

I have a problem with a menu and I've tried some solution, but I am not getting close.

[image: Here is my activity]

The selected layout is an invisible layout that it becomes visible when you press the green button on the top left. The problem is that I can't make it invisible if I press outside the layout. Note that on this activity's main layout, i will display fragments. So there is no moment when the activity's layout is visible. It will always have a fragment displayed over it.

Here is my attempt:

This is the button `OnClickListener`.

```
    dropDownBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            DropDownItemsFragment d = new DropDownItemsFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.menu_container, d);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            if (menu_container.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                menu_container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                menu_container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });
```

And here is my `onTouchEventFunction`

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    // MotionEvent reports input details from the touch screen
    // and other input controls. In this case, you are only
    // interested in events where the touch position changed.

    float x = e.getX();
    float y = e.getY();

    switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            if (x > menu_container.getWidth() && y > menu_container.getHeight()) {
                main_container.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                menu_container.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think you have to make your **menu_container** layout invisible when you receive MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN. Because while moving, you always call invisible, and if this does not work, try to return true if ** ACTION_MOVE**, return false if it's not ** ACTION_MOVE**.

Comment: It is not working either way.

Comment: In my opinion, I have to create an event that reads every time I click outside the layout to make it invisible. But how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem comes down to geometry.

### First

You should check for different action, specifically `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` or `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` since these events are easier to handle. Once you get it working you can adapt to your specific needs.

### Second

Your current check 
`x > menu_container.getWidth() && y > menu_container.getHeight()` is probably not what you're looking for, since this will be `true` only inside red rectangle marked on picture below.

[image]

### Solution:

In order to make sense of what "outside of View" is, you'll be better off using Rect coordinates of your view, and check if received touch coordinates falls in the "outside". This code snippet will help you get going:

```
int x = (int) event.getX();
int y = (int) event.getY();
Rect rect = new Rect();
switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            if (menu_container.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect)) {

                if ( !(x > rect.left && x < rect.right && y > rect.top && y < rect.bottom))

                    Log.d(TAG, "Clicked Outside the view ");
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Action Down: coordinate x: " + x + " coordinate y: " + y);
            break;
}
```

This approach will also give you flexibility if you ever decide to put your View in the center of the parent View.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it your way and it worked as well. I also found a more direct method.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (menu_container.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        menu_container.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

This is what I tried and it worked perfectly.